# Select a specific cell within the range of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that records attendance of students. I have a macro that merges `ActiveCell.Range("A1:A50")` and writes "Sunday" in it. The things that I am trying to do are:

1. To check if the active cell is in column D to AH.
2. If step 1 is true, then activate cell 9 of that column ("In case the active cell is F20 or F100 then macro should change it to F9 without changing the column that the user has selected)

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Sunday()
Dim myarr(4 To 34) As Integer
Dim col As Integer
col = ActiveCell.Column
If col = myarr Then
   ActiveSheet.Cells(9).Select

   'code to merge range and enter "Sunday"

Else
   On Error Resume Next
End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Sunday()

    Dim col As Long
    col = ActiveCell.Column

    If col >= 4 and col <=43 Then

       ActiveSheet.Cells(9, col).Select

       'code to merge range and enter "Sunday"

    Else

    End if

End Sub
```